# Erro ao tentar criar uma view a partir de um controller e uma model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ao tentar cria uma View a partir da Controller, usando Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web Api, eu tenho esse erro. Isso somente acontece, quando eu:

1) Modelo -> List
2) Classe do modelo -> quando busco na pasta Model um arquivo, no meu caso esse: OperatorDetailsModel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se resolve isso?

Comment: atualize o pacote Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Comment: @NetinhoSantos, quando eu tento atualizar tenho esse erro: **O pacote Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 não é compatível com netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). O pacote Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 dá suporte a: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)**